# Obtaining a family of functions given a property

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose a function family is given by the following defining identity:

$$f\left(u, \frac{rs}{r+s}\right) = \frac{f(u,r)f(u,s)}{f(u,r) + f(u,s)} $$

for all $u, r, s$ in the real domain, or the complex domain

What can be said about the functions $f$, and how do we obtain some nontrivial representatives of the family if non-empty?

Comment: I wouldn't expect any other solutions aside from $f(x)=Cx$, where I leave the $u$ dependence out, since it's arbitrary

Comment: can you prove there are no other solutions?

Comment: I can't. Don't take my word for it

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Consider $$g \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)=\frac{1}{f(x)},$$ you will get the linearity property for it:

$$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$

This is equivalent to the functional equation in the OP.

The $u$ dependence can be arbitrary.